# Single Photo loads from gallery until I go to another page [Swipe JS]

Tags: html, css

I'm using jQuery Mobile for a simple mobile website.
Using SwipeJS for swiping through pictures.
On the iPhone, all 3 photos load and swipe automatically.
On the iPad, only the first photo and hence doesn't swipe as it does read the other photos in the gallery.

All three photos only loads, after I go load another page and then come back to the page.

Javascript is turn on

```
<div id = "slider">
  <ul>
    <li style = 'display:block'><a href="../customer/19"><img src="../firstPhoto.jpg", width="80%"></a></li>
    <li style = 'display:none'><a href="../customer/20"><img src="../secondPhoto.jpg", width="80%"></li></a>
    <li style = 'display:none'><a href="../customer/21"><img src="../secondPhoto.jpg", width="65%"></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a glitch with Swipe JS 1.0, I upgraded to [Swipe 2.0](https://github.com/bradbirdsall/Swipe/tree/swipe2) and it fixed the issue.

More info here - https://github.com/bradbirdsall/Swipe/issues/16